# For loop does not save changes to csv files in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am trying to change columns within csv files to combine the date and time columns into one. The code works when I attempt it with a specific csv file without the for loop however it fails to save any of the changes to the csv files when i attempt to make the code into part of a loop:

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/elsam/Documents/Year 3/Final EN3300 Project/Machine Learning/Data/locations/asp/row/noaa/data_id.csv')
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
for f in [df, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19, df20, df21, df23]:
    f['Date'] = f['Date'].astype(str)

    f = f.loc[(f['Date'] != '0')]

    f['year'] = f['Date'].str[:-4]
    f['month'] = f['Date'].str[-4:-2]
    f['day'] = f['Date'].str[-2:]

    f['time'] = f['time'].astype(str)

    f.loc[(f['time'] == '0'), 'time'] = '000'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '2'), 'time'] = '002'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '11'), 'time'] = '011'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '20'), 'time'] = '020'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '30'), 'time'] = '030'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '40'), 'time'] = '040'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '45'), 'time'] = '045'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '46'), 'time'] = '046'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '47'), 'time'] = '047'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '53'), 'time'] = '053'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '55'), 'time'] = '055'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '56'), 'time'] = '056'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '59'), 'time'] = '059'
    f['hour'] = f['time'].str[:-2]
    f['minute'] = f['time'].str[-2:]

    f['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(f[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']])
df.to_csv('C:/Users/elsam/Documents/Year 3/Final EN3300 Project/Machine Learning/Data/locations/asp/row/noaa/5 min NOAA.csv')
```

Before the for loop I have a list of csv files to read formatted the same as the code for df csv file and after the for loop I have a list of csv files to save formatted the same as the code for the df csv file as shown above. However none of the changes within the for loop seem to have been saved to any of the csv files. I was wondering why this is as the code works without the for loop when f is replaced with df, df2, etc.

Comment: The code only shows you loading and saving `df`.  Are you actually saving the other dataframes?

Comment: You are only saving one dataframe to disk (named df), and that occurs outside of your loop. I think you want to loop over filenames and open and rewrite each dataframe within the loop.

Comment: I am loading and saving all the other data frames df-df23. I only included the code to load and save df as the code to load and save the other data frames is identical to that of df, just with different file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this -

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/elsam/Documents/Year 3/Final EN3300 Project/Machine Learning/Data/locations/asp/row/noaa/data_id.csv')
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
for i, f in enumerate([df, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df19, df20, df21, df23]):
    f['Date'] = f['Date'].astype(str)

    f = f.loc[(f['Date'] != '0')]

    f['year'] = f['Date'].str[:-4]
    f['month'] = f['Date'].str[-4:-2]
    f['day'] = f['Date'].str[-2:]

    f['time'] = f['time'].astype(str)

    f.loc[(f['time'] == '0'), 'time'] = '000'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '2'), 'time'] = '002'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '11'), 'time'] = '011'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '20'), 'time'] = '020'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '30'), 'time'] = '030'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '40'), 'time'] = '040'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '45'), 'time'] = '045'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '46'), 'time'] = '046'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '47'), 'time'] = '047'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '53'), 'time'] = '053'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '55'), 'time'] = '055'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '56'), 'time'] = '056'
    f.loc[(f['time'] == '59'), 'time'] = '059'
    f['hour'] = f['time'].str[:-2]
    f['minute'] = f['time'].str[-2:]

    f['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(f[['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute']])
    f.to_csv('C:/Users/elsam/Documents/Year 3/Final EN3300 Project/Machine Learning/Data/locations/asp/row/noaa/5 min NOAA_' + str(i) + '_'.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried your alterations but I got an error code for the last line:
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Users\elsam\Documents\Year 3\Final EN3300 Project\Machine Learning\Code\Data Compilation.py", line 298, in <module>
    f.to_csv('C:/Users/elsam/Documents/Year 3/Final EN3300 Project/Machine Learning/Data/locations/asp/row/noaa/5 min NOAA_' + i + '_.csv')
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Okay, I made a change. Please change the code